# Pressing back button shows "This document is no longer available" instead of freshly requested page

Tags: jsf, back-button, jsf-2.2

i am struggling with the above mention issue i am using code to clear the cache of browser

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { 
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

i am logged in application and hit back button it gives directly message to me 
"This document is no longer available." please suggest me on that

Comment: Could you try doing a redirect before showing the page in the first place, like `return "/newpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";` in the action method

Comment: could you please specify in brief  i did not understand your point. will pleased add code snippet on that comment